# Scala local return?

Tags: scala, controls, closures

I've just discovered that `return`s in following closure will return from function `findPackage`

```
def findPackage(name: String, suffix: Option[String] = None): Path = {
    logger.debug("Looking for package {} with suffix {}", name, suffix)
    val path: Path = using(Files.newDirectoryStream(appDir)) {dirs =>
        for (val path <- dirs) {
            val matcher = packagePattern.matcher(path.getFileName.toString)
            if (matcher.matches() && matcher.group(1).equals(name))
                if (suffix.isDefined) {
                    if (matcher.group(2) != null && matcher.group(2).equals(suffix.get))
                        return path
                } else
                    return path
        }
        throw new PackageNotFoundException(this, name, suffix)
    }
    logger.debug("Found package is {}", path)
    path
}
```

Can I somehow do a *local* return please? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Or you could get rid of your loop and replace it with what you're trying to do: "find"

```
def findPackage(name: String, suffix: Option[String] = None): Path = {
    logger.debug("Looking for package {} with suffix {}", name, suffix)

    def matching(path : Path) : Boolean = {
        val matcher = packagePattern.matcher(path.getFileName.toString)
        matcher.matches && matcher.group(1).equals(name) && (!suffix.isDefined || (matcher.group(2) != null && matcher.group(2).equals(suffix.get))
    }

    val path: Path = using(Files.newDirectoryStream(appDir)) {dirs =>
       dirs find matching getOrElse {throw new PackageNotFoundException(this, name, suffix)}
    }

    logger.debug("Found package is {}", path)
    path
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I fully support James Iry's suggestion, but for the sake of demonstration:

```
def findPackage(name: String, suffix: Option[String] = None): Path = {
    logger.debug("Looking for package {} with suffix {}", name, suffix)
    val path: Path = using(Files.newDirectoryStream(appDir)) {dirs =>
        try {
          for (val path <- dirs) {
              val matcher = packagePattern.matcher(path.getFileName.toString)
              if (matcher.matches() && matcher.group(1).equals(name))
                  if (suffix.isDefined) {
                      if (matcher.group(2) != null && matcher.group(2).equals(suffix.get))
                          return path
                  } else
                     return path
          }
          throw new PackageNotFoundException(this, name, suffix)
        } catch { case e:scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl[Path] => e.value}
    }
    logger.debug("Found package is {}", path)
    path
}
```

**What changed?**

I have added a `try{}` block around the body of the anonymous function and then `catch` expression at the end looking for `scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl` exception, then I extract and pass on the return value.

**Why it works?**

Returning from a nested anonymous function raises `scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl` exception which is caught by the host function or method.

[Scala Language Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), section 6.20 Return Expressions:

> ... Returning from a nested anonymous function is implemented by
>   throwing and catching a scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnException. Any
>   exception catches between the point of return and the enclosing
>   methods might see the exception. A key comparison makes sure that
>   these exceptions are only caught by the method instance which is
>   terminated by the return.
>
> If the return expression is itself part of an anonymous function, it
>   is possible that the enclosing instance of f has already returned
>   before the return expression is executed. In that case, the thrown
>   scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnException will not be caught, and will
>   propagate up the call stack.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, by defining a local method:

```
def findPackage(name: String, suffix: Option[String] = None): Path = {
    logger.debug("Looking for package {} with suffix {}", name, suffix)

    def search(dirs: List[File]) = { // not sure what the type of dirs actually is
        for (val path <- dirs) {
            val matcher = packagePattern.matcher(path.getFileName.toString)
            if (matcher.matches() && matcher.group(1).equals(name))
                if (suffix.isDefined) {
                    if (matcher.group(2) != null && matcher.group(2).equals(suffix.get))
                        return path
                } else
                    return path
        }
        throw new PackageNotFoundException(this, name, suffix)
    }

    val path: Path = using(Files.newDirectoryStream(appDir))(search _)
    logger.debug("Found package is {}", path)
    path
}
```

or by throwing some exception and catching it:

```
def findPackage(name: String, suffix: Option[String] = None): Path = {
    logger.debug("Looking for package {} with suffix {}", name, suffix)
    val path: Path = using(Files.newDirectoryStream(appDir)) {dirs =>
        try {
            for (val path <- dirs) {
                val matcher = packagePattern.matcher(path.getFileName.toString)
                if (matcher.matches() && matcher.group(1).equals(name))
                    if (suffix.isDefined) {
                        if (matcher.group(2) != null && matcher.group(2).equals(suffix.get))
                            throw new ReturnException(path)
                    } else
                        throw new ReturnException(path)
            }
            throw new PackageNotFoundException(this, name, suffix)
        }
        catch { case ReturnException(path) => path }
    }
    logger.debug("Found package is {}", path)
    path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble, and I solved it by propagating any ControlThrowable I might find, like it says [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.ControlThrowable)

```
def asJson: JsValue = {
  val key = "classification.ws.endpoint"

  configuration.getString(key).map{ url =>
    try {
      return WS.url(url).get().await.get.json
    } catch {
      case ce : scala.util.control.ControlThrowable => throw ce
      case e => throw InvalidWebServiceResponseException("Error accessing '%s'".format(url), e)
    }
  }.getOrElse {
    throw new MissingConfigurationException("No value found for '%s' configuration".format(key))
  }

}
```

Note that in this case, just removing the "return" statement solves the problem...