# How does Scala implement return from within an expression?

Tags: scala, return, implementation, anonymous-function

For example, if we have a method like

```
def find[A](xs: Seq[A], p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  xs.foreach(x => if (p(x)) return Some(x));
  None;
}
```

(of course there is a library function for this, this is just an example). How does the execution escape `foreach` when the inner function `return`s?

Or in

```
def foo(x: AnyRef): String =
  process(x match {
    case (s: String) => s;
    case _           => return "";
  })
```

how does the execution avoid running `process` when `return ""` is issued?

Comment: [Scala uses exceptions for flow control like this](http://dev.bizo.com/2010/01/scala-supports-non-local-returns.html) (key word to search for is `NonLocalReturnControl`). See also *Scala Language Spec, section 6.20*

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707524/247533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foo` example depends on which of

```
def process(s: String): String
def process(s: => String): String
```

it is.  I'm assuming the former, since you suggest `process` isn't run.  This is just the way it always works when passing an argument--you do the argument-creation work first, then call the method.  Since you run into a `return`, it's easy: you just call the appropriate `return` from bytecode while creating the argument*, and never go on to invoke the method.  So it *is* just a local return.

The `find` example is a little more involved.  Let's try a maximally simple example motivated by a `foo` which requires a nonlocal return:

```
class Nonlocal {
  def pr(s: => String) = { println(s); "Printed" }

  def foo(x: AnyRef): String = pr(x match {
    case (s: String) => s;
    case _           => return "";
  })
}
```

The body of `foo` is equivalent to

```
import scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl
val temp = new AnyRef
try {
  pr(x match {
    case s: String => s
    case _         => throw new NonLocalReturnControl(temp, "")
  })
}
catch {
  case nlrc: NonLocalReturnControl[_] if (nlrc.key eq temp) =>
    nlrc.value.asInstanceOf[String]
}
```

The key things to notice is that a sentinel object is created so that these things can be arbitrarily nested without clobbering each other, and that `NonLocalReturnControl` carries the correct value back.  Unsurprisingly, this isn't exactly cheap compared to just returning, say, an `Int`.  But since it creates an exception without a stack trace (safe, because it can't escape: the `catch` block is guaranteed to catch it), it's not *that* bad--is about as bad as calling a trig function or summing an array with a few dozen entries.

Note also that `pr` only gets *partly* executed before the exception gets it.  In this case, it doesn't print anything because the first thing it does is try to use `s` to fill in an actual string, but then it hits the exception which drops control back to `foo`.  (So you get an empty string back from `foo`, but you don't print anything.)

* <sup>Actually, in bytecode it tends to be a jump to the end of the method, with the load/return there.  Irrelevant conceptually, though.</sup>